# self::STAT yii how do with some condition

Tags: yii

I have some relation in Yii model `self::STAT`:

```
'countItem' => array(
   self::STAT,
   'DocumentCategory',
   'parent_id'
),
```

I want condition `WHERE is_deleted = 0` it possible to do?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's. Quit using yii.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'countItem' => array(
    self::STAT, 'DocumentCategory', 'parent_id', 'condition' => 'is_deleted = 0'
),
```

Take a look at point 4. about relational query options:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

Answer (score 0):

Or may this solution help:

```
'select'=> 'COUNT(parent_id)', 'condition'=>'is_deleted=0',
```